# Message:The parameter is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, iis-6

I have a web site/app developed on my local machine.  A customer does an order.  Data they enter during the order is saved to a SQL Server DB duing each step in the order.

If they naviagte away from the current order there is an option to resume orders - where the info is pulled back from the Table in the DB and displayed on screen.  Now this works 100% on my own Dev machine.

Howvere I have deployed it to another server and it is not working as epxected - I can see the info gets stored to teh DB table ok.  However when I hit the page to resume - no data is returned.  I looked at SQL Profiler and it never hits the DB I am interested in (yet I can see from SQL Profiler that it hits the DB earlier (on logon to the site)

I have they opened Dev Tools in chrome - on the network tab - on my own Dev machine - I can see the data in there (in a page called JSONService.aspx - which is how I get the data back)

However in my other server environment I get the below:

```
ListOfErrors: [{CompletionCode:null, Message:The parameter is incorrect.
 }]
0: {CompletionCode:null, Message:The parameter is incorrect.
 }
CompletionCode: null
Message: "The parameter is incorrect.
↵"
Objects: null
RequestStatus: "Failure"
```

I will be investigating this myself and if I get a resolution I will update my answer with it - does anyone possibly have any ideas of things I could try in the meantime - cannot think what I am missing at the minute?

Comment: Do you not get a stack trace with the error?

Comment: My money is on a screwed up connection string.

Comment: No - not on this other sever - it doesnt have VS where I can debug - that is what is everything that is shown in the Network Tab in Chrome for the partcular aspx page that is doing the call to DB and as I mentioned it works as expected on my local machine where I have Visual Studio

Comment: but the connection string should be fine - it logs on the user to the site - it retrieves this info from another Table in the same DB??

Comment: Anything interesting in the event log on the server?

Comment: If you are using asp.net's membership stuff, it often uses its own connection string to connect.  Not sure how yours is setup though.